# Crontab every 5 minutes

Tags: linux, unix, cron

How could i tell crontab to run every 5 minutes, but starting at the second minute of the hour. In other words, i would like to execute my script when `minute % 5 = 2`.

For example, my script should run at :

```
08:02
08:07
08:12
08:17
...
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This should be moved to unix.SE.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

```
2,7,12,17... command
*/5 ....     sleep 120 ; command
```

1. Write explicit all minutes in `crontab`
2. Run `sleep` command before the actual command

Comment: on Linux you can also use `sleep 2m` instead of 120 seconds

Comment: In crontab(5) manual page it is said in the "EXTENSIONS" section that "Ranges can include "steps", so "1-9/2" is the same as "1,3,5,7,9"." So 2-59/5 should also work.