# Crontab every five minutes

Tags: linux

I am trying to set up a crontab in linux that runs every 5 minutes

I need to run the following command:

```
/var/local/orders/ pmtw-print.jar localhost pmtw root itsm
```

This is what I think I should have but doesn't appear to be working:

```
5 * * * *  java -jar ~/var/local/orders/ pmtw-print.jar localhost pmtw root itsm
```

Thanks

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crontab every 5 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260406/crontab-every-5-minutes)

Answer (score 1):

To run every 5 minutes, use the following. The one you have would run at 5th minute every hour.

```
*/5 * * * *  java -jar ~/var/local/orders/ pmtw-print.jar localhost pmtw root itsm
```

Comment: Correct (question tagged Linux). On Solaris and AIX the syntax is not supported, ans you need 5,10,15,20,..,55 * * * *